# How to get the top predictions of isolationforest in sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, outliers

I am using `IsolationForest` as follows to detect outlier data points of my dataset.

```py
clf = IsolationForest(max_samples='auto',
                        random_state=42,
                        behaviour="new",
                        contamination=.01)
clf.fit(X)
y_pred_train = clf.predict(X)

outliers = []
for item in np.where(y_pred_train == -1)[0]:
    outliers.append(df_nodes[item])
```

I want the predicted outliers as a ranked list. That is, I want to know what was the most potential outlier and the next and so on (maybe sorted using some probability of prediction). I was trying to find out a way to do it in `sklearn`. However, I still could not find a way. Please let me know a suitable way of doing this.

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `predict`, use `decision_function`.

From the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.IsolationForest.html):

> Methods
>   decision_function(self, X)    Average anomaly score of X of the base classifiers.

Then, you can rank them based on their anomaly score. The lower this value, the more abnormal the observation is.